# Set project configurations using Visual Studios custom template wizard

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to create a C++ project template using the custom project wizard. I just need a simple template for an empty C++ CLI application that uses an external library, i.e I need the wizard to set the following settings found under `Project -> Properties`:

```
Configaration Setting -> VC++ Directories -> Executable Directories 
Configaration Setting -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories 
Configaration Setting -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories 
Configaration Setting -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies
```

It seems I need to modify `default.js` more specifically the function `AddConfig` which contains:

```
function AddConfig(proj, strProjectName)
{
    var config = proj.Object.Configurations('Debug');

    var CLTool = config.Tools('VCCLCompilerTool');
    // TODO: Add compiler settings

    var LinkTool = config.Tools('VCLinkerTool');
    // TODO: Add linker settings
}
```

I need help in setting the project settings here.